# app-dev.php 404 error but app.php work

Tags: php, symfony

when i run my domain

> test.lapille-symfony.eu/web

it's work

> test.lapille-symfony.eu/web/app.php

it's work

but

> test.lapille-symfony.eu/web/app-dev.php

i've 404 error

i search why on google and stack overflow but found nothing.
i found for app.php 404 but dont for app-dev.php

app.php
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

```
/**
 * @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

app-dev.php

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup
// for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

/**
 * @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have uploaded `app-dev.php` with name `app_dev.php` since

```
test.lapille-symfony.eu/web/app-dev.php
```

does not work, but

```
test.lapille-symfony.eu/web/app_dev.php
```

works.

Comment: ho well thanks. But sry another question why i've the symfony toolbar when i used app.php ?

Comment: sorry, I don't know symfony, so can't answer that

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no `app-dev.php` in Symfony SE. Normally it comes in 2 environment dev (`app_dev.php`) and prod (`app.php`)

We normally develop applications using `app_dev.php` so that a Symfony profiler is available to assist you in debugging. So my suggestion is to check your filename under `web` directory and access accordingly.